# Electromagnetic wave reflected by a metal surface previously charged

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose the case of a metal sheet made of perfect conductor, then illuminate with a monochromatic light the surface from a known distance and measure the reflected wave, Which would be any difference if the surface was submitted to a constant voltage?

Comment: I'm not an expert but my estimation is that the electrons although at a a potential are still free enough to interact with the EM field of the photon, thus no change,